# What is the best API to combine C++11 async/futures with Windows asynchronous IO?

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous, c++11, windows-8

Especially the upcoming **Windows** 8 (with Metro) will require that any **IO is programmed asynchronously**. In C#/.Net there seems to be special `await` and such like constructs for that and the JavaScript API will have its own mechanism for that to work.

What will be the **C++11-integration** for that? Is the a concise example (eg. reading an image from a file for display?) for modern (or upcoming) Windows? If it's **using C++11 features** I would expect that `async` or `future` is involved?

Comment: async and/or future will probably not be involved. Windows 8 async stuff is integrated with PPL and task-based programming and cooperative blocking. async and future is thread based and thread blocking.

Comment: Oh yes, from PPL I have heard, at least.

Comment: @Pavel I don't quite see how? The C++11 std::future does not have a set_wait_callback which would allow one to override the blocking implementation with a cooperative block. The only way to compose std:future with task-based schedulers is to suffer the overhead of the Concurrency::Oversubscribe(true) feature of the ConcRT scheduler. What am I missing? And with WinRT a std::future would just block the win thread? That's not how WinRT works, from my understanding it expects cooperative blocking.

Comment: I think this video might have some relevant information, http://bartoszmilewski.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/c11-concurrency-tutorial-5-tasks/

Comment: @ronag Yes, I was mistaken there. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Tips and tricks for developing Metro style apps using C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-845T) presentation covers this at 59:13. The raw interface uses callback objects. In practice, people are likely to use the simplified interface offered by PPL.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 async will probably be done through PPL. You can read more about that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/09/22/windows-8-asynchrony-with-ppl.aspx).

From my understanding, Windows 8 and PPL uses task-based scheduling and cooperative blocking. While std::async and std::future use thread based scheduling and preemptive blocking. Thus they are not compatible.

Comment: `std::future` looks to me like task-based scheduling.

Comment: Well it might look like that. But all of its blocking functions are non-cooperative, which I believe makes it a bad fit for task-based schedulers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Asynchronous-08009a0d